# Como alterar o nome do banco de dados de destino ao realizar a restauração? (Classe Restore C# .net)

Tags: c#, sql-server, backup

Estou fazendo o backup e o restore de um banco de dados SQL Server utilizando as classes Backup e Restore do C# .NET, com o Smo.
O problema é que após realizar o backup do banco de dados com o nome, por exemplo "Teste", não consigo restaurar o banco com outro nome, o que é possível utilizando ferramentas, como o Management Studio. Seria possível restaurar o banco de dados com outro nome através da classe Restore?

```
public void Restore(String dataBaseName, pathFile)
    {
        bdi = default(BackupDeviceItem);
        bdi = new BackupDeviceItem(pathFile, DeviceType.File);           

        Restore rs = new Restore();

        rs.NoRecovery = false;

        rs.SqlVerify(srv);        

        rs.Devices.Add(bdi);

        rs.Database = dataBaseName;

        rs.SqlRestore(srv);

        rs.Devices.Remove(bdi);
    }
```

Comment: Você pode colocar um exemplo do seu código na sua pergunta?

Comment: Experimente mudar o nome do database na hora de fazer o backup, não o restore. Se funcionar, coloco como resposta.

Comment: Pensei em fazer isso, porém se eu colocar na hora de fazer o backup ele não irá encontrar o banco para copiar.

Comment: Já fiz isso mas não com a classe Restore e sim com SqlCommand e sqlDataAdapt executando uma SQL para restaurar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acordo com [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7079637/1639385) no StackOverflow em inglês, você deve fazer o seguinte:

1. Atribua o novo nome desejado para o banco na property `Restore.Database`.
2. Atribua o valor true para a property `Restore.ReplaceDatabase`.
3. Especifique novos arquivos de dados e logs na property `Restore.RelocateFiles`.